# bash: export: `-Xmx512m': not a valid identifier when I set MAVEN_OPTS variable

Tags: linux, bash, maven, opensuse

I'm on OpenSuse, I'm following [this tutorial to set up Maven](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm).

When I ran this :

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

I got the following error:

> bash: export: `-Xmx512m': not a valid identifier

I've followed that tutorial's steps, the Maven I downloaded is Version 3.5.2.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need quotes around the value, as it contains a space.

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
```

Comment: When using these quotes... `”` and `“` are **not** what you want.   `"` is what you want.

Answer (score 6):

The space in between both options makes the shell interpret this as two different arguments. You need to protect the options with quotes:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
```

Comment: Thank you, I've just noticed that